# Adding Warp Speed to a Conversion family

Tags: delphi

I have added a Speed family to the ConvUtils using meters per second as the base.

i.e.

```
   Cf := RegisterConversionFamily('Speed');
   RegisterConversionType(Cf,'Meters per second'    ,1);
   RegisterConversionType(Cf,'Speed of Light'       ,0.000000003335641);
   RegisterConversionType(Cf,'Speed of Sound(Mach)' ,0.0029411765);
```

Now I would like to add 'Warp Speed' as a type.

I have the formula

```
V = wf^3 * C
```

Where:
   V = Velocity
   wf = Warp Factor
   C = Speed of light

How can I add a formula to add a type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can register own formulas for conversion:

```
function ToWarp(const AValue: Double): Double;
begin
   Result := YourFormula1;
end;

function FromWarp(const AValue: Double): Double;
begin
   Result := YourFormula2;
end;

RegisterConversionType(Cf,'Warpspeed' ,ToWarp,FromWarp);
```

Comment: Almost there but how can I put that formula into the functions. The warp factor(wf) value is not known yet

Comment: Steve, the warp-factor value is either *given* to the function (for `FromWarp`) or *returned* by the function (for `ToWarp`). You certainly wouldn't expect to know the value in advance. That's what the functions are for.

Comment: I have spent 2 days trying to get the 2 formula to work.  How do I convert the formula to work in delphi?

Comment: function ToWarp(const AValue: Double): Double;
begin
   Result := Power(Avalue,3)*(300000*1000);
end;

function FromWarp(const AValue: Double): Double;
begin
  Result := Power(AValue /(300000*1000),1/3);
end;


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Showmessage(FormatFloat('#,###',(convert(2,FWarp,FMS))));
  Showmessage(FormatFloat('#,###',(convert(2400000000,FMS,FWarp))));
end;
--in create ..
begin
  Cf := RegisterConversionFamily('Speed');
  FMS := RegisterConversionType(Cf,'Meters per second'    ,1);
  FWarp :=RegisterConversionType(Cf,'Warpspeed' ,ToWarp,FromWarp);
end;

Comment: @bummi When I use `RegisterConversionFamily` and `RegisterConversionType` the family and type will stay avaible to use in any form application just call the ConvUtils? If I run this example will show the new family?